# Finding namespace and libraries in VS 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I need following namespaces to use native wpf property grid however, VS 2010 doesn't recognize them. I went over available namespaces and libraries under "Add Reference" but no luck.

An suggestions will be appreciated.

```
System.Activities
System.Activities.Core.Presentation
System.Activities.Presentation
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should consider accepting more answers to your previously asked questions.

Comment: A simple web search answers this question very quickly (first link for me).

Comment: @Saluce, can you be specific and tell me which question I have ignored?

Comment: @CodingGorilla, did that and ran into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.aspx  however, it is not clear to me why VS is not showing it.

Comment: @amitkohan What version of the .Net framework are you using?

Comment: @amitkohan: your answer is below. So dlls are not directly in VS2010. You need to find is reference Assemblies of Microsoft

Comment: You have accepted 5 answers on 16 eligible questions.  You really should look over those other 11 questions, mark the answer that best helped you, or rephrase your question to get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dll available is this location, on a 64-bit OS.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

Comment: Yes, this worked out fine and now I can add the namespace. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find what DLL to add is to check with MSDN Library

1. Find the help for the class you need. Ex: [System.Activities.Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activity.aspx)
2. On the page, look for the assembly name. It is locate in the top part of the page and in bold. Ex : **Assembly:** System.Activities (in System.Activities.dll)
3. Add the reference to the DLL that is between the parentheses and you will have access to the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. I usually do the same but in this case when I typed `using System.Activities;`  it will underline it with red. I tried Add Reference t add the DLL but couldn't find it.